# React Flux application not showing data correctly

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I was trying to refactor my React application, which is using callbacks to flux.
I am almost done, but not able to solve a little bug. The application shows youtube videos by fetching data from youtube.
Now when the first time the application load, it is showing the videos correctly.
[image]

The select functionality is working fine and also the search functionality 
[image]

But if i select a video after the first render and then do a search . It doesn't shows the first video of the search.
[image]

I know the issue is in this part of the code in **video_detail.js** file.
My git repo for this app [git repo for youtube-player-flux](https://github.com/nabendu82/youtube-player-flux)

Please help me solve this little bug.

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.item) {
      return <li className="media-right">Loading...</li>;
    }
    let video;
    Object.keys(this.state.userSelected).length === 0
      ? (video = this.state.item)
      : (video = this.state.userSelected);

    const videoId = video.id.videoId;
    const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;

    return (
      <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
        <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={url} />
        </div>
        <div className="details">
          <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
          <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Please find it in the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y8bfij)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to replicate your issue.

Comment: When the apps open then click on any video in the list, it will change the video in player. Then search for a something in Search Bar. Ideally the video player should show the first video from the search, but it stills shows the old video.